# Native Android webview in Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webview

I try to create native webview in Unity3d project.

```
 public void load_webview() {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID

        AndroidJavaClass webView = new AndroidJavaClass("android.webkit.WebView;");
        AndroidJavaClass unityActivity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject activity = unityActivity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        activity.Call("setContentView", webView);
        webView.Call("loadUrl", "https://www.google.com"); 

        #endif
    }
```

But i get error :

```
E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: android.webkit.WebView;
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: android.webkit.WebView;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
```

Another class, for example "Toast", works perfectly :

```
..
AndroidJavaClass toastClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
..
```

How to import Webview class? I take "android.webkit.WebView" path from Android Studio project.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of "android.webkit.WebView;"

Comment: JeanLuc, thanks =) It is very stupid mistake. The code is still wrong, but I'll solve it by myself and post the correct solution later

Answer (score 0):

It requires a bit more work to launch a WebView. I would suggest you use one of the open source plugins instead of trying to create one from scratch.

This one has worked fairly well for me in the past:
[gree/unity-webview on GitHub](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview)